# Using opacity yields wrong scaffold's background color

Tags: flutter, background-color, alpha

```
main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: CountryScreen(),
      ),
    );
```

and in the `CountryScreen` build's widget method

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen.withAlpha(125),
  body: Column( ...
```

Scasffold's background color is below and obviously it's a wrong color because `Colors.lightGreen.withAlpha(125)` mixes with black.

[image]

How to awoid such behaviour when using alpha or opacity with a color?

For instance, if I use a solid color `Colors.lightGreen` for the scaffold backgroud it doesn't mix up with a black and it is ok.

Comment: Can you share what your desired result looks like?

Comment: you would like to have translucent main window and see other apps that are behind (for example for flutter desktop app)?

Comment: @tomerpacific the desired resulted color for the scaffold backgroung should be a color if apply opacity 0.5 to `Colors.lightGreen`

Comment: @pskink not at all. the main window backgroud color should be comletely opaque with a color `Colors.lightGreen.withAlpha(125)`

Comment: if you use non opaque colors the visual appearance depends on what color is behind: for example what is color `Colors.red.withAlpha(0)`?

Comment: if you use non opaque colors the visual appearance depends on what color is behind: for example what is color `Colors.red.withAlpha(0)`?

Comment: @pskink it gives black backround because  `withAlpha(0)` makes a color comletele transparent.

Comment: the same is with `127` if background color (behind) is white the result is different from black,  if you want to see it in action try `Color.alphaBlend(Colors.lightGreen.withAlpha(125), Colors.red)` and `Color.alphaBlend(Colors.lightGreen.withAlpha(125), Colors.white)`

Comment: @pskink using `withAlpha(125)` is like a desatutating a color and make it twice lighter compared to original color, right? but in the topic example it mixes up with black color

Comment: no, it will not be desaturated (as i said it will depend on what color is behind): if you want to desaturate use `HSVColor` and its `saturation` property (ranges from 0..1)

Comment: @pskink using `alphaBlend` seems give a desired result but I think there shold be another solution in a such case

Comment: it is `HSVColor` - `S` stands for `saturation`

Comment: @pskink wraping the column in a container with a color of `Colors.lightGreen.withAlpha(125)` and not using scaffold bacground color is sipmler

Comment: additional `Column` and `Container` just to specify the color? if you dont like `Color.alphaBlend` or `HSVColor` just use `Colors.lightGreen.shade400` or `Colors.lightGreen.shade300` or similar shades (`shade500` is the same as `Colors.lightGreen`)

Comment: @pskink it's one more solution

Answer (score 4):

#### Use custom `PageRouteBuilder`, when you navigate to your page.

Like:

```dart
Widget opaquePage(Widget page) => PageRouteBuilder(
   opaque: false,
   pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) => page,
);
```

Now navigate to your page:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  opaquePage(MyScaffoldWidget),
)
```

Then you should be able to make your **`Scaffold`**'s background transparent:

```dart
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(.85),
  ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

wrap your `Scaffold` in `Container` widget and set container color to white.

like this:

```
return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Scaffold(
           backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen.withAlpha(125),
           body: Column( ...
```